# Is there any obvious drawback to use a no assignment swap?

Tags: c++

I was implementing (for training purpose) a Bubble Sort template function:

```
template<typename iterInput,
         typename predicate>
void BubbleSort(iterInput first1,iterInput last1,predicate func)
{
    bool swapped(false);
    do
    {
        swapped = false;
        iterInput begin = first1;
        iterInput beginMinus = first1;
        ++begin;
        for (;begin != last1; begin++,beginMinus++)
        {
            if (func(*beginMinus,*begin) )
            {
                std::swap(*beginMinus,*begin);
                swapped = true;
            }
        }
    }
    while(swapped);
}
```

When I have realized that this function will not work for class with no assignment operator, like this one (forgive me for the bad name):

```
class NoCopyable
{
public:
    explicit NoCopyable(int value) : value_(value) {}
    NoCopyable(const NoCopyable& other) : value_(other.value_) {}
    ~NoCopyable() {}
    bool operator<(const NoCopyable& other) { return value_ < other.value_; }
    void setValue(int value) { value_ = value; }
    std::ostream& print(std::ostream& os) const { return os << value_; }
private:
    NoCopyable& operator=(const NoCopyable& other);
    int value_;
};

std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, const NoCopyable& obj)
{
    return obj.print(os);
}

struct PrintNoCopyable
{
    void operator()(const NoCopyable& noCopyable) { std::cout << noCopyable << '\n'; }
};
```

The compiler raises this error Error    1   error C2248: 'NoCopyable::operator =' : cannot access private member declared in class 'NoCopyable'

So, I have slightly modify the code using instead of the std::swap function my version of the swap function, here is the code:

```
template<typename T1,
         typename T2>
void noAssignmentSwap(T1& t1,T2& t2)
{
    T1 temp(t1);
    t1.~T1();
    new (&t1) T1(t2);
    t2.~T2();
    new (&t2) T2(temp);
}
```

The code compiles and gives the right result. However I am not completely sure, I remember a Sutter's article that suggest you to avoid playing with the objects life time. The article just warns you by playing with fire without actually giving you any real reason. I can see problem in exception safety if the copy constructor of T1 or T2 can throw. However there is the same problem in the standard version if the assignment operator is allowed to throw.

Here the question, can you see any possible drawbacks in this version of swap?

Cheers

Comment: explicit destructor calls are rarely needed... looks iffy imho

Comment: Why are you using two different types in swap? if they are different using placement constructor for one object with the address of the other is going to be anyway very bad...

Comment: @good point, it should be just one template parameter

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The difference is that when the assignment operator fails, you still have the same number of objects.

If you destroy one object and fail to create a new one, one object is lost! If it was part of a container, the container's state is probably also invalid.

Answer (score 8):

Apart from anything else, if a class does not have an assignment operator, its designer probably did not intend it to be swapped. If they did that, they probably disabled copy construction too, so your new swap function still won't work.

As for your assertion that Standard Library containers do not need assignment - that is true so long as you don't want to actually do anything useful with them. Does this code compile for you?

```
#include <vector>
using namespace std;

struct A {
    private:
        void operator=( const A &);
};

int main() {
    vector <A> v;
    v.push_back( A() );
    v[0] = A();     // assignment needed here
}
```

I think it won't.

Comment: @Neil Butterworth if the copy constructor of the object is disabled the object cannot be used with the stl container, so there is no so much to sort.

Comment: @Alessandro So you are dealing with objects that can't be assigned, but can be copied? Such are quite rare, in my experience. And your question is explicitly about swap().

Comment: @Alessandro Teruzzi The standard containers require their contained objects to be assignable anyway, so I agree with Neil here.

Comment: @Neil Butterworth I think they are less rare then you think. In fact the stl container are not requiring assignment operator, in general for template function (and class) less requirement means more flexibility. I don't feel comfortable with this version of swap that I have provided and Bo Persson gave me the reason.

Comment: @Mark B which standard container require assignment operator? Some functions in std requires assignment but not the container itself.

Comment: @Alessandro That depends what you mean by "container" and "function" - see my edit.

Comment: @Neil: any type with a const or reference instance variable falls into this "rare" category of copy-constructible-but-not-assignable objects

Comment: @High And such are (justifiably) rare, as I said. In fact, I've never written such a thing or encountered one (except as special cases here on SO) in over 25 years of commercial C++ programming. YMMV.

Answer (score 4):

You need a copy ctor instead of an assignment operator, but the two are sufficiently similar that at least in a typical case, you'll have both or you'll have neither. IOW, I don't think this generally accomplishes much.

I'd class it right along side the xor-swap trick: interesting, but generally useless.

Answer (score 3):

It might be confusing to a future maintainer of the code.